# What is the best way to sponsor the creation of new hyphenation patterns for languages without them?

Tags: hyphenation

I'm working for a small company that would be interested in sponsoring the creation of new TeX hyphenation patterns. We're especially interested in funding minor languages and ensuring the final product is open source.

Is there a TeX freelancer forum that the community recommends? Or would it simply be better to place a bounty on new hyphenation patterns?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The hyphenation patterns are centrally maintained here

https://github.com/hyphenation/tex-hyphen/issues

So you could make a feature request for new ones, mentioning that you could sponsor the work.

An issue there is more likely to reach someone familar with building hyphenation patterns than someone familiar with the language of interest. You probably need both kinds of people, but you have to start somewhere...